# how to transform jArray into jobject

Tags: c#, json

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` lib with C# and encountered a problem. I have a jArray as below:

```
[{"category": "computer","subcat": "desktop"},
 {"category": "category","subcat": "laptop"},
 {"category": "television","subcat": "LCD"}]
```

and I want it to be transformed as a jObject as below:

```
{"computer": ["desktop","laptop"],
 "television": ["LCD"]}
```

Here want I need is a general method that can handle this type of transformation. Which means this method could also do the trick even if the jArray has a 3rd level property. e.g.

**from**

```
[{"typeA":"a","typeB":"a1","typeC":"a11"},{"typeA":"a","typeB":"a1","typeC":"a12"},
 {"typeA":"a","typeB":"a2","typeC":"a21"}]
```

**to**

```
{"a":{"a1":["a11","a12"],"a2":["a21"]}}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you had a go at the LINQ query provider which comes with Newtonsoft's library?

Comment: Show us your attempt please.. don't just give us a task to do for you. Even if it's pseduocode, at least show us you've spent some time trying to do it yourself.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for reply. Yeah, I knew it is not wise to ask without trying myself, you have my apology. I'm just wondering if this is a common request with using Json and there's already an existing function to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: @Z.Sawyer Well, the quickest way to do it would be to convert it to a .NET object, and transform it using LINQ (`GroupBy()` and some `Selects` should get the job done).

Comment: @Z.Sawyer Added a quick and (terrible) example to get you started. Hate using `dynamic`, but I don't see a better way.

Comment: `{"type":"a","type":"a1"}` is that even valid with the same keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXTREMELY quick and dirty - with vast room for improvement, but this will get it done:

Use like this:

```
var input = @"[{""type"":""a"",""typeB"":""a1"",""typeC"":""a11""},
               {""type"":""a"",""typeB"":""a1"",""typeC"":""a12""},
               {""type"":""a"",""typeB"":""a2"",""typeC"":""a21""}]";

var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<tmp>>(input);
var result = doIt(b, "type", "typeB", "typeC");
```

With this implementation:

```
private string doIt(IEnumerable<tmp> objs, params string[] g)
{
    var t = CollapseOrGroup(objs,g);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
}

private dynamic CollapseOrGroup(IEnumerable<tmp> objs, IEnumerable<string> props) 
{
    var firstProp = props.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstProp == default(string))
        return objs;

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(tmp));
    var m = Expression.Property(p, firstProp);
    var l = Expression.Lambda(m, p).Compile() as dynamic;

    if (props.Count() == 1)
    {
        return Enumerable.Select(objs, l);

    } else {    
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<dynamic, tmp>> g = Enumerable.GroupBy(objs, l);   
        return g.ToDictionary (o => o.Key, o => CollapseOrGroup(o, props.Skip(1)));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{"a":{"a1":["a11","a12"],"a2":["a21"]}}
```

Search for `Newtonsoft` in NuGet and download `JSON.Net` for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem using java.
Currently, the solution from my side is to traversal the initial ArrayJSON, then figure out the wanted format.

You can define Type1 as a model, List as the member variable, same operation with Type2 using Type3, this will help make your code easy to be organised.